# min and max value in javascript

Tags: javascript

This example works fine, but I would just add something like min and max values,

to stop scrolling at the start and at the end point:

```
var X = 0;
var BBB = $('.BBB');

$('#buttonA').click(function() {
X--;
Y = X * 200;
Z = 'translate3d(' + Y + 'px, 0px, 0px)';
BBB.css('-webkit-transform', Z);
});

$('#buttonB').click(function() {
X++;
Y = X * 200;
Z = 'translate3d(' + Y + 'px, 0px, 0px)';
BBB.css('-webkit-transform', Z);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9CDSr/)


Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add variables with min and max values. Then, inside the functions, check if limit was reached.

```
var X = 0, min = -2000, max = 0;
var BBB = $('.BBB');

$('#buttonA').click(function() {
X--;
Y = X * 200;
if(Y < min) {X++; return}; // If reach the limits, stop.
Z = 'translate3d(' + Y + 'px, 0px, 0px)';
BBB.css('-webkit-transform', Z);
});

$('#buttonB').click(function() {
X++;
Y = X * 200;
if(Y > max) {X--; return}; // If reach the limits, stop.
Z = 'translate3d(' + Y + 'px, 0px, 0px)';
BBB.css('-webkit-transform', Z);
});
```

Comment: it does not work.. I don't understand

Comment: I've edited the answer, check: http://jsfiddle.net/9CDSr/1/